# Drawing a Fractal Tree in Python using Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am attempting to draw a fractal tree using Python. In particular, I am trying to understand the following code, found [here](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Recursion/pythondsintro-VisualizingRecursion.html)

```
def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 5:
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(20)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.left(40)
        tree(branchLen-10,t)
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branchLen)
```

My question specifically, is that I do not understand what happens after the completion of the final step (that is, `t.backward(branchlen)`). How does the value of the variable `branchlen` change after this step? I have attempted to do follow the algorithm and manually construct the tree using pencil and paper, but to no avail. Help from anyone will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: After `t.backward(branchLen)`, _nothing_ happens except that the function returns. Then the function that called you—in this case, usually another instance of `tree`, with its own separate `branchLen` local variable—continues on from after that call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not understand what happens after the completion of the final step (that is, `t.backward(branchlen)`).

Nothing happens; you just return to your caller, which then resumes at the line after the `tree` call.

Of course because this is a recursive function, your caller is usually going to be another instance of `tree` (unless you're all the way up at the top of the stack).

> How does the value of the variable branchlen change after this step?

It doesn't. But each instance of `tree` has its own locals.

So, for example, let's start at the top.

First, we call, say `tree(25, t)`. Inside here, `branchLen` is `25`.

Now, it does `t.forward(25)` and `t.right(20)`. Then it does `tree(25-15, t)`. That's a new call to `tree`, and inside that new call, `branchLen` is `10`.

So, that new call does `t.forward(10)` and `t.right(20)`. Then it does `tree(10-15, t)`. That's a new call to `tree`, and inside that new call, `branchLen` is `-5`. So that new call returns immediately, since the `if` fails, and we return back to the call where `branchLen` is `10`. It does `t.left(40)`, and then calls `tree(10-10, t)`. Again, a new call, where `branchLen` is `0`, which returns immediately, so we're back to the call where `branchLen` is `10`. We do `t.right(20)`, then `t.backward(10)`, then return.

And now we're back to the outer call, where `branchLen` is 25. It continues on with `t.left(40)`, then calls `tree(25-10, t)`. That's again a new call to `tree`, but time `branchLen` is `15` rather than `10`. Everything is pretty much the same as the last paragraph, so I won't repeat it, and it ends with that call returning.

And now we're back to the outer call, where `branchLen` is 25 again. It continues on with `t.right(20)` then `t.backward(25)`, and then it's done, and it returns.

And since that was called by our top-level code, we're done.

---

If the recursion is still throwing you, let's make a non-recursive version that only goes 2 steps instead of N steps:

```
def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 5:
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(20)
        little_tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.left(40)
        little_tree(branchLen-10,t)
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branchLen)

def little_tree(littleBranchLen,lt):
    if littleBranchLen > 5:
        lt.forward(littleBranchLen)
        lt.right(20)
        lt.left(40)
        lt.right(20)
        lt.backward(littleBranchLen)
```

Now it should be obvious that when `tree` calls `little_tree` the first time, when it returns, it returns back to the `t.left(40)` line in `tree`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have another question though. When we're back to the outer call where `branchLen` is 25, why does it continue on with `t.left(40)` while skipping over the initial `t.forward()` and `t.right()` commands? To be more specific, I understand that at the end of the first iteration, `t.backward(10)` moves backward along the branch with the turtle ending up at the bottom of the branch, pointed in the direction of the branch. The next steps, I suppose, would be to execute the `t.left(40)` and `t.forward(branchlen)`, where `branchlen`=10. I don't follow how this is done.

Comment: @SumukhAtreya: When you call a function, and it returns, you _always_ pick up with the next line of code, you don't start over at the beginning again. Think of a non-recursive example and it should be clearer. I've edited the answer to show what that looks like.